# Is ti well type interface?

Tags: typescript

It is interface for userInfo

```
export interface UserInfo {
    mail: string;
    pw: string;
    phone: string;
    name: string;
    name02?: string;
    salt?: string;
}
```

and I should make modifyinfo type below is first type

```
export type ModifyInfo = Partial<Pick<UserInfo, 'name' | 'name02' | 'mail' | 'phone'>>
```

This type have problem.

```
modifyArr.push(modifyInfo[i]);
```

On above code have type error. So, I add some code in modify type

```
export type ModifyInfo = Partial<Pick<UserInfo, 'name' | 'name02' | 'mail' | 'phone'>> & {
    [key: string]: string | undefined;
};
```

Error has beeen resolve. but, I don't know it is good way. Because, I don't know modify type represents the optional type well. modify type's all key is optional.

What do you think?

Comment: All your code seems to work fine and the properties on both ways you have defined the type are optional. I think there's nothing with doing it the way you are doing it.  Here's a [TS Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/NapkEw)